# Merge Replication On Live SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, merge-replication

I have successfully configured merge replication on my local SQL server by creating two instances making one as Publisher and other as distributor. 
Now to show demo to my client i need it to configure live by making my local system as Subscriber and any live sql server as publisher, can any one guide me that where should i configure live server ? As if i go to any paid SQL Standard edition it will cost me more than my salary , i just need to show demo to client. Can i install SQL Developer on any windows hosting? or there isn't any other option than buying server

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Setup Merge Replication Demo on your local, then install 2 SQL Server instance or you can perform on same server as well. But for the better understanding you can consider one instance as a publisher and second as a subscriber.

Now, configure replication with Publisher and Distributor on Server-1 and subscriber on Server-2.

Comment: Its working fine on local, now i want to make my local instance as subscriber and some live server as publisher, but where should i configure live free? as i just have to show demo to client, i cant afford paid MS SQL Standard

Comment: You can use Azure SQL Server Instance on free quota. Just perform and remove it, once you are done.